# How to get an object value when property name can change

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got the following reply from an Ajax response:

```
[
   {s_main: "apple1"},
   {s_main: "apple2"},
   {s_main: "apple3"},
   {s_main: "apple4"}
]
```

I can get the response array via the following code:

```
success: function(data) {
    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
        return {
            label: item.s_main,  // how to make this more generic?
        }   
    })
);
```

I can get the new array, which is:

```
[{ label: "apple1" },  { label: "apple2" }, { label: "apple3" }, { label: "apple4" }]
```

...but the `s_main` property name can change to another name, so I want to get the values by just doing something like `item[0]`, `item[1]`, ..., but if I do that I just get an array with undefined values.

How can I get the values without specifying a hard-coded property name?

Comment: Do you mean that the `s_main` property might not be there, but that there is another property of which you do not know the name, but you still want to get its value? So, is the question: how can I get the value of an object property when the object only has one property, but I do not know its name?

Comment: I know the name just like s_main, s_product, s_price etc... But one name needed when one time. It depends the button which the user pushed. So I just want to combine many fuction to one function, avoiding the redundancy by the repeating  most the same code.

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing the actual buttons and click handlers you have. But would this solve your issue? `label: Object.values(item)[0]` Or does `item` have more than one property at the same time?

Comment: @trincot it works~You save my day~thanks a lot! Wish you a happy day~

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get a property value even when the name of that property could be different.

In that case you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values): it returns an array of property values, and since apparently you are using objects with just one property, it will be an array with just one value.

In your code it would look like this:

```
return {
    label: Object.values(item)[0]
}
```